# YouTube's search function in IOS

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uinavigationitem

http://coolappsman.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/YouTube-App-Search.jpg

Hello, I am looking for some implementation tips for YouTube's search-function. I want to implement exactly the same thing but without the function "displaying tips based on the search-term".

With other words, I want a simpler version. How can I make the NavigatorBar disappear when the user clicks on the "search-button" and then make the NavigatorBar appear again after the user searched what they looked for? If you have seen the app its pretty clear what I am trying to explain.

Anyone know a good tutorial to implement something like this? What methods do this require? I am grateful for all tips. Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jesper.
Concept you want to implement is quite hard to do, that is highly customized control. Instead of showing results in the same view, a new controller is pushed with results table.

However, you can start with UISearchDisplayController. See [Apple's TableSearch example.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html)